# Getting "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" only the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a ToDo app. This app has two screens: **Todos** and **Done**. I'm using BottomTabNavigator to switch between these screens. These two screens has list of todos. The **todos** component shows the undone todos and the **Done** component shows the done todos. There's a checkbox on the left and Trash icon on the right of every single todo. When a todo from **Todos** page is checked then it moves to the **Done** page. The issue is: after switching to the **Done** screen from **Todos** for the first time then after unchecking the todo there gives this warning:

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
in SingleTodo (at Done.tsx:74)**
After this, the app is running perfectly. As I'm not sure which component is causing this error that'w why I'm sharing the minimal version of the code.

I have set up **Bottom Tab** navigator component like this:

```js
import stuff..
...

const HomeTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
          let iconName = '';
          size = focused ? 25 : 20;
          if (route.name === 'To-Do') {
            iconName = 'clipboard-list';
          } else if (route.name === 'Done') {
            iconName = 'clipboard-check';
          }

          return <FontAwesome5Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#0080ff',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#777777',
        tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold'},
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen name="To-Do" component={Todos} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Done" component={Done} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeTab;
```

As you can see, there are 2 components here. One is **Todos**. The code for this component is as follows:

```js
import stuff...
...

const Todos = ({navigation}) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const {todos}: {todos: TodoInterface[]} = useAppSelector(
    state => state.todoReducer,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    loadTodos();
  }, []);

  const loadTodos = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('todos').then(todos => {
      const parsedTodos: TodoInterface[] = JSON.parse(todos || '{}');
      dispatch(setAllTodo(parsedTodos));
    });
  };

  return (
    <HideKeyboard>
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <FlatList
          data={todos.filter(todo => todo.done !== true)}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            const firstChild = index == 0 ? {marginTop: 5} : {};
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.todoWrp, firstChild]}
                onPress={() => todoPressHandler(item.todoId)}>
                <SingleTodo  // ***The code for this one is given below***
                  title={item.title}
                  subtitle={item.subTitle}
                  done={item?.done}
                  todoId={item.todoId}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, i) => item.todoId}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addBtn} onPress={addBtnHandler}>
          <FontAwesome5 name="plus" color="#fff" size={25} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </HideKeyboard>
  );
}
```

The code for **SingleTodo** is as follows:

```js
const SingleTodo = ({title, subtitle, done: doneProp, todoId}: Props) => {
  const [done, setDone] = useState(doneProp);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const {todos}: TodosType = useAppSelector(state => state.todoReducer);

  const checkBoxHandler = (val: boolean) => {
    const todoList: TodoInterface[] = [...todos];
    const index = todos.findIndex(todo => todo.todoId === todoId);
    todoList[index].done = val;
    AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todoList)).then(() => {
      dispatch(setAllTodo(todoList));
      setDone(val);
    });
  };

  const deleteHandler = () => {
    const todoList: TodoInterface[] = [...todos];
    const index = todos.findIndex(todo => todo.todoId === todoId);
    todoList.splice(index, 1);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todoList)).then(() => {
      dispatch(setAllTodo(todoList));
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <CheckBox
        value={done}
        onValueChange={val => checkBoxHandler(val)}
        style={styles.checkbox}
      />
      <View>
        <Text style={[styles.title, GlobalStyle.IndieFont]}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.subtitle, GlobalStyle.IndieFont]}>{subtitle}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.trashWrp}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteHandler}>
          <FontAwesome5Icon
            style={styles.trashIcon}
            name="trash"
            color="#e74c3c"
            size={20}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SingleTodo;
```

The code for **Done** component is similar to **Todos** component. The only changes is on the *data* property of the  component

```js
<FlatList
  data={todos.filter(todo => todo.done === true)}
  ...
  other props...
  ...
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening every time you use this, it is just shown once to not spam the console.

```
 const checkBoxHandler = (val: boolean) => {
    const todoList: TodoInterface[] = [...todos];
    const index = todos.findIndex(todo => todo.todoId === todoId);
    todoList[index].done = val;
    AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todoList)).then(() => {
      dispatch(setAllTodo(todoList));
      setDone(val);
    });
  };

  const deleteHandler = () => {
    const todoList: TodoInterface[] = [...todos];
    const index = todos.findIndex(todo => todo.todoId === todoId);
    todoList.splice(index, 1);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todoList)).then(() => {
      dispatch(setAllTodo(todoList));
    });
  };
```

Basically, you call the function, and the todo is unmounted from the state, but the function is not completed yet and you get that warning.

The solution is to lift everything related to the deleteHandler  and checkBoxHandler from your children (Todo) to your parent (Todos), and pass it to Todo as props. Since parent is always mounted, deleting the todo will not unmount the parent and therefore, delete function will not be interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. I think I get the error message clearly now. On checkBoxHandler, the component was unmounted after the dispatch() method. Hence, I was updating the  state using setDone on the unmounted component. That's why the error occured.  I lifted the setDone() method up before updating the state and the error is gone.